# Using Python Arcade and Tkinter together hangs the application

Tags: python, tkinter, arcade

I am trying to build an app that generates dynamic visual models (using Python 3 with PyCharm on Windows). I am using Arcade for the main viewing / user interaction window, and Tkinter for preliminary data input, model parameters, numeric output, errors and warnings etc.

I find that if I open a tk window (e.g. messagebox.showinfo or messagebox.error) while the Arcade window is open, the application hangs. Here is a minimal snippet that recreats the problem:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
import arcade

tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Greetings", "hello")
app = arcade.Window(500, 300, "Let's play")
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Greetings", "hello again")
```

The second messagebox never opens, and a whopping 30% of the CPU is active while Python is doing nothing except (in theory) waiting for user input.

Comment: I don't know arcade.. but don't you have to do something with 'app' after you've created it?

Comment: I think it's a known problem on windows that tkinter will misbehave if you try to show a dialog before the root window has been displayed. It's been years since I've had access to a windows machine, though.

Comment: JeffUK: app = arcade.Window opens an arcade window. Of course in the real world I put objects in that window and manipulate them. I was trying to pinpoint the problem with a minimum of code.

Comment: Brian Oakley: my original program had a 
root = tkinter.Tk() # initiate tkinter
before the first call to showinfo. It doesn't seem to alter the behavior of the program.

Comment: If the `arcade.Window` launches some kind of game loop, you may not receive the second message. Try adding `while True: input("Enter text: ")` instead of `app = arcade.Window()`.

Comment: a) No. arcade.window just opens a blank window. The game loop is initiated by arcade.run further down the code.

Comment: b) Brian Oakley suggested a possible direction: that the bug is OS-related. If someone can try the above code in a non-Windows environment and report I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @IlanSharon You can test your code on a different OS using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). You may need to [install the python3-tk package to work with tkinter](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#install-x11-python).

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works for the static text in Arcade. It won't update text dynamically. See [Ethan Chan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118733/using-python-arcade-and-tkinter-together-hangs-the-application/68159077?noredirect=1#comment130116597_68159077) below.

You can launch `tkinter` app from the `arcade`:

```
import arcade
import tkinter as tk

class ArcadeApp(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(400, 300)
        self.root = None

    def on_closing(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        self.root = None

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text('Click to launch Tkinter', 200, 150, arcade.color.RED, 30, align='center', anchor_x='center')

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.root.geometry('400x300')
            self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_closing)
            label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Greetings from Tkinter!')
            label.config(font=('', 20))
            label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
            self.root.mainloop()

ArcadeApp()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image: Arcade]

[image: Tkinter]

Comment: A problem with this is the arcade screen hangs when the tkinter window is open.

Comment: No, it's not. Works correctly on Win 11 / Python 3.10 / Arcade 2.6.15

Comment: no, it really hangs. If you try to change the text in `draw_text` every frame, it will stop redrawing and updating the text whenever the `tkinter` window is open. But when you close the `tkinter` window, the arcade screen resumes. As Bryan Oakley said, `tkinter` does have problems with this kind of stuff. And arcade has stuff with GL context that causes this sort of problems.

Comment: @EthanChan tested your scenario. You're right - I've updated my answer.